# SQL Add column to normalize time of different Oil Wells

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on normalizing all my oil wells' production data so that I can easily plot them as if they all were turn on at the same time. The way to do this is to add a "Normalized Time" row to the table by each well. The normalized time will reset to 1 every time a new well is introduced. I'm looking how to add the "Normalized Time" column below:

[image]

I'm working in MS Access SQL. How would I go about adding the new "Normalized Time" column? I need it so that all my wells appear to start producing at the same time and are easier to compare.

Comment: There is not a single question mark in your post.  How are we to know what you would like help with?  Also, if relevant, a statement or two about *why* and *how* this NormalizedTime column is supposed to solve your issue would be appropriate.

Comment: @SamAxe made changes, thank you and apologies... relatively new to this.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822825.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This proposed solution seems totally pointless - such a column is easily calculated whenever needed instead of being stored, and thus is of zero semantic content. Please explain the actual business problem you are attempting to solve with this proposal so that we can attempt to assist you with that instead.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens I need the column because I'm loading the data into Spotfire for graphical purposes. I'd strongly prefer to have it created in a table which I load in than have to make it Spotfire itself. Perhaps there is an easy way to do it in Spotfire which I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query:

```
Select 
    *,
    (Select Count(*) From YourTable As T 
    Where T.well_name = W.well_name And T.rpt_date <= W.rpt_date) As [Normalized Time]
From
    YourTable As W
Order By
    well_name,
    rpt_date
```